# asp.net create a dynamic grid with sql data and make it editable

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to implement a new project. I want to write an SQL table dynamically into e.g. an asp:gridview. And this grid should be editable.

I found some solutions, but they were all static. But it is essential that the table is dynamic, because I want to include different SQL tables in the grid. (The SQL tables sometimes change, columns are removed or new ones are added. Therefore a static solution is not applicable.

Ideally, the editing function should work like in an Excel document. After changing the data, it should be written back to the SQL table with a save button.

Is that even possible? I haven't found a solution to this problem in at least the last 4 hours.

Thank you for your help

Greetings

---

Update

---

```
//HTML Code:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1>Personaldaten</h1>
            <asp:GridView ID="personal_data" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" text="Save"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

//Code behind:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Editable_SQL_Table
{
    public partial class table : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
            SqlDataAdapter sda;
            SqlCommandBuilder scb;
            DataTable dt;

            public form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            public void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Database = Personal; Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true");
                sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT* FROM dbo.MyTable", con);
                dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
                sda.Update(dt);
                MessageBox.Show("Table updated");
            }
    }
}
```

I tried to use the coding from user2980341 but I have a problem with "dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;" I think for "dataGridView1" I should use the id from my Gridview, but I does not work. The debugger says, that he does not recognise "personal_data". Also the function "InitializeComponent();" is undefinded.

Thanks for any further help, I am currently working on the following solution:

```
//HTML
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="table.aspx.cs" Inherits="Editable_SQL_Table.table" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1>Personaldaten</h1>
            <asp:GridView ID="personal_data" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server" OnRowUpdating="personal_data_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="personal_data_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="personal_data_RowEditing"></asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

//Code behind
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Editable_SQL_Table
{
    public partial class table : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string table = "dbo.Mitarbeiter";
            string query = "SELECT * FROM" + " " + table;
            string ConnectionString = "Server = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Database = Personal; Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true";
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection))
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    personal_data.DataSource = dt;
                    personal_data.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void personal_data_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            personal_data.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        }

        protected void personal_data_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            //personal_data.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        }

        protected void personal_data_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            //personal_data.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a *very* broad question.  Have a read of **[ask]** and then update the question with more relevant info, especially any code to show what you've currently got and explain what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:
Add DataGridView and a Button element on your form. Then append this code to your elements:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlDataAdapter sda;
    SqlCommandBuilder scb;
    DataTable dt;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (@"Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT* FROM dbo.MyTable", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
        sda.Update(dt);
        MessageBox.Show("Table updated");
    }
}
```

}

This program connects to your SQL database and retrives an SQL table from that database. Changes to databse are updated using button1. You cannot however remove or add columns trough this solution.

Comment: I have updated my question above. I have some problems regarding "dataGridView1" and "InitializeComponent();" Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, I am not that familiarcwith asp.net.